# Git submodule inside Docker

Tags: git, docker, yarnpkg

My app have structure like this:

```
/app
  /web
    /submodule
    package.json
    yarn.lock
    Dockerfile
.gitsubmodule
docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile in /app/web:

```
# build
FROM node:10 AS build-env
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn install

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn build

# run
FROM nginx

COPY --from=build-env /usr/src/app/storybook-static /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In package.json `submodule` include as dependency:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "submodule": "file:./submodule",
```

When docker build running `yarn install` command, an error is thrown:

```
Building web
Step 1/9 : FROM node:10 AS build-env
 ---> c0cfd9444538
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31d2e6122773
Step 3/9 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 385af24cf951
Step 4/9 : COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 861576eec879
Step 5/9 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Running in edde173d5035
yarn install v1.9.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Package "submodule" refers to a non-existing file '"/usr/src/app/submodule"'.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If running `yarn install` without docker everything is fine. How to solve this problem?

Comment: When you reach the `RUN yarn install` step, what files actually are in `/usr/src/app` in the container's filesystem?  Try `docker run --rm -it 861576eec879 sh` and looking around (where that image ID is the "step 4" result).  Why isn't your application's source there?

Comment: I used https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/. In this moment in container only `package.json  yarn.lock`. Apparently I must transfer to the container my `submodule`?!

Comment: Yes, you need to do that.